# How to bind typed DataTable to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datarow

With the below code, I am trying to customise the DGV without relying on the knowledge of the actual database column names. But it does not work. Can I know what is the correct way to do it? Thanks.

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable { ... }

public class MyDataRow : DataRow 
{
    public FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public SecondProperty { get; set; }
    public ThirdProperty { get; set; }
}

void LoadDataGridView()
{
    DataGridViewTextColumn colFirst = new DataGridViewTextColumn();

    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    ...
    colFirst.HeaderText = "First Property";
    colFirst.DataPropertyName = "FirstProperty"; // doesnt work ?
    ...
    ...
    dgv.Columns.AddRange = { ... };
    dgv.DataSource = new BindingSource(mydatatable);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just bind DGV to your datatable and rename the column headers?

Comment: @Kamyar As stated, the objective is to hide the actual database column names from the UI implementation.

Comment: if you are throwing a `DataTable` around, IMO you've already mixed data and UI. You need some kind of object-based domain model to avoid that.

Comment: @Marc Gravell well.. i do agree with you, but i am trying to see if .NET has anything I can minimise it.

Comment: No. Short of wrapping each row with your own typed object; it doesn'in this case. The usual arsenal of tools are disarmed entirely by ITypedList.

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable` implements (indirectly*) `ITypedList`, which always takes precedence over the reflection type model. As a consequence, any properties you add are largely irrelevant for data-binding purposes, since the property definitions don't involve reflection at any point, but instead look at the columns defined on the `DataTable`.

Or less verbose: that won't work, and can't work.

*= via `IListSource` which returns the `DefaultView`, which is a `DataView` which implements `ITypedList`